# reducing the word problem for dtm to sat / cnf-sat / 2-sat

Tags: reductions, satisfiability, 2-sat

word problem: given a language L through a deterministic turing machine, is the word w in the language L?

the problem should be decidable, since if there is a deterministic turing machine i can simply turn that into a dfa take the word w go through the dfa step by step and see if i end in an accepting state?

I now want to know if there is a way to reduce the word problem to sat / cnf-sat or 2-sat. can't think of a way that i could do that so i wanted to ask on here. my professor said i should take a look at the proof for cnf-sat / 3-sat in NP and then see what happens when i translate the word problem for dtm in the same way so i would guess i should check what happens when i search for a way where i try to translate the word problem into a sat/cnfsat/2-sat problem. thanks in advance

Comment: The answer depends on the language $L$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus the language L is given through a Deterministic Turingmachine

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no because the problem seems undecidable.

You can reduce the halting problem to it.

Comment: the problem is decidable for languages of type-1 / 2 and 3. its undecidable for type-0 languages.

Comment: Your question states "given a language $L$". There is no other hypothesis.

Comment: just updated the post